# migrate gitlab ci to azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gitlab-ci

Been working on migrating the `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `azure-pipelines.yml`. I am not able to find equivalents of some specific gitlab keywords in azure.

For eg:
(1)

```
rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: manual
  timeout: 5 minutes
  interruptible: false
  allow_failure: true
```

(2)

```
    paths:
      - $ARTIFACTS_DIR/
    expire_in: 1 week
  timeout: 15 minutes
```

How to have the particular job working only on a specific rule? The equivalent of predefined variable
`$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID`, the keys like `rules`, `if`,`when`,`timeout`, `interruptible`,`allow_failure`, `artifacts`, `paths`, `expire_in`, `timeout` on azurepipelines.yml file?

Some insights would be great?

Answer (score 2):

GitLab CI and Azure DevOps are two different systems, so keep in mind not every feature of GitLab CI has a one-to-one match in ADO and there are likely to be significant differences in how they are used.

For the features you mentioned, here are the analogs in Azure DevOps:

| GitLab keyword | ADO Equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| `rules` | [`jobs.job.condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines) or [`steps.step.condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps?view=azure-pipelines) |
| `allow_failure` | [`jobs.job.continueOnError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines) (also available in steps/tasks) |
| `timeout` | [`jobs.job.timeoutInMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines) |
| `when:manual` | See [Manual Intervention task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops) (set and first task and use `condition:` on this task for equivalent of `rules:if:when:manual`) |
| `artifacts` | see [`steps.publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-publish?view=azure-pipelines), [`steps.download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-download?view=azure-pipelines), [pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), and [build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) |
| `expire_in` | see [retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). |
| `interruptible` | no analog: all jobs can be cancelled in ADO and this cannot be prevented. Closest solution would be to set a high [`cancelTimeoutInMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines) value |

Predefined variables like `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID` only exist for GitLab CI, not Azure DevOps. Azure DevOps pipelines do have their own [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) -- `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` would be the equivalent of `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID`, for example... but this may depend on exactly how you are using ADO with your repository.